# Image and Text box in SlideView Header

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am making windows 8.1 app using https://slideview.codeplex.com in the Windows 10 with help of Visual Studio 2013. I could successfully disable Right Pane. Also I could add TextBox which I could set from each page separately.  But when I add Image with the TextBox it will not work but if I put only Image without Textbox it will work. I did below code.

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Background="#48649F">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding library:SlideApplicationFrame.ImageSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="None" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="6,12" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26" Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" />
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Once that is solved I want to make Image Source dynamically.  For that I added below code in **SlideApplicationFrame.cs** but it is not helping

```
#region ImageSource (DependencyProperty)

/// <summary>
/// Content for the header
/// </summary>
public object ImageSource
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", 
                                            typeof(object),                
                                            typeof(SlideApplicationFrame),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(null));

#endregion
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please any help on this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake I was not looking at **ContentPresenter** Where I added one more property as below

`Tag="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}"`

and it started as my requirement